# Python syntax to open gnome-terminal and execute multiple commands

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am developing a Auto install x2go script in Python (for ubuntu/linux especially)
i'v come to where i got an gnome terminal open with the command 
`os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo apt-get update -y ; exec bash\"'")`

it works fine, but now comes my problem. 
i have to execute more than the one command in the same terminal window, but i cant figure out how to split or define two commands in the same line.
i have tried `--tab -e [command]` but it doesn't seem to work with my previous syntax 
`os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/ppa --tab -e sudo apt-get update ; exec bash\"'")`

i would be glad if i could get some help with this :)

Best Regards

Comment: Have you tried to join it the same way you would in bash? os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/ppa && sudo apt-get update ; exec bash\"'")

Comment: when run it returns with: "error: need a single repository as argument"

Comment: Hmmm. I just tested it on my local machine exactly as I type it and it worked fine :s

Comment: $ cd /tmp
$ nano test.py
$ cat test.py
import os
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:x2go/ppa && sudo apt-get update ; exec bash\"'")
$ python test.py

Comment: I got it to work now!!!
many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this page from Google, the answer was resolved in comments.

Simply chain the commands like you normally would in bash

```
os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/ppa && sudo apt-get update ; exec bash\"'")
```